# How to save two data in once in same table using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I am creating referral code functionality where the user will enter refer code while registering  and then I am getting the user from referral code and adding credits on his account at the same time I want to add credit for the user who just registered but my only one data got saved not both

I added code for the Adding credits for whose referral code is using another user to register also wrote code for adding credits for the current registering user but unable to add credit on both users at same time

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userForRegisterDto.Email))
        {
            userForRegisterDto.Email = userForRegisterDto.Email.ToLower();

            if (await _repo.UserExists(userForRegisterDto))
                return BadRequest("User For this mail/contact already exists" );
        }

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userForRegisterDto.ContactNo))
        {
            if (await _repo.UserExists(userForRegisterDto))
                return BadRequest("User For this mail/contact already exists");
        }

        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<User>(userForRegisterDto);
        var createdUser = await _repo.Register(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

        int id = createdUser.Id;
        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForDetailedDto>(createdUser);

        if (userForRegisterDto.ReferralCode != null)
        {
            string message = "Congratulations you recieved 100 rs credit on your account";
            var getUserByRefCode = await _repo.GetUserByReferralCode(userForRegisterDto.ReferralCode);
            var getCurrentCreatedUser = await _repos.GetUser(id);

            if (getUserByRefCode != null)
            {
                ReferralStatus status = new ReferralStatus()
                {
                    Credits = 100,
                    OfferAddedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    IsCreditsUsed = false,
                    ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
                };

                getUserByRefCode.ReferralStatus.Add(status);
                getCurrentCreatedUser.ReferralStatus.Add(status);
                await _repos.SaveAll();
                return Ok(new { userToReturn, message });
            }
        }

        return Ok(userToReturn);
}
```

Comment: use AddAsync instead of Add and try it again.

Comment: Can we see what your methods are inside the repo rather than just leaving us in the dark here please.

Comment: Is `SaveAll()` running `SaveChanges()` or `SaveChangesAsync`?

Comment: Thanks for taking time for my question, but i figured out the issue is i was using add in both model but for second time i am not sending any model and directly i am writing .Add function but in ef core there provision to pass entity model each time when i am adding the data so 
answering for Tubs question yes inside `saveall()` method i had `SaveChangesAsync()` and its working fine